# Combine two columns in a table

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table, I do not have any control over the source code of the table (auto generated), I can just control its CSS.  1st column has text, 2nd column has image, 3rd column has text.  I want to show 3rd column text underneath 2nd column image, how can I achieve this?  Following is my code sample.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="view-title">
                <h2>Title 1</h2> </td>
            <td class="view-image">
                <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="linktoimage.jpg" width="250" height="150" alt=""> </td>
            <td class="view-description">
                <h3>Here is some text</h3> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="view-title">
                <h2>Title 2</h2> </td>
            <td class="view-image">
                <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="linktoimage1.jpg" width="250" height="150" alt=""> </td>
            <td class="view-description">
                <h3>Some more text</h3> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't sound easy.  You might have to abuse the CSS rather heavily.  Start by eliminating the borders between the columns.  Then maybe use relative positioning to make one column's content seem to appear in the other column, which has padding sufficient to make a space for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that seems to work. First I made all the table elements into blocks, then I made the image and the description `display:table-row;` so they would align one under the other and floated the title to the left. [Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w577tuzz/1/) if you want to play around with it.

```css
table, tbody, tr, td {
    display:block;
}
.view-title {
    float:left;
}
.view-image {
    display:table-row;
}
.view-description {
    display:table-row;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="view-title">
                 <h2>Title 1</h2> 
            </td>
            <td class="view-image">
                <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://placekitten.com/250/150" width="250" height="150" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td class="view-description">
                 <h3>Here is some text Some more text Some more text</h3> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="view-title">
                 <h2>Title 2</h2> 
            </td>
            <td class="view-image">
                <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://placekitten.com/250/150" width="250" height="150" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td class="view-description">
                 <h3>Some more text Some more text Some more text Some more text</h3> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I cannot add CSS to `table` `tbody` as it is auto-generated

Comment: Huh? What do you mean? What does it being auto generated have to do with adding CSS?

Comment: Source code is generated by CMS, it will only let me to add css to `tr` and `td` tags

Comment: You're going to add all the CSS inline in the tags? What about an external CSS file or a `<style>` tag in your page head...? If even those are not possibilities, this is quite the limiting factor and should be mentioned in your question.

Comment: My solution probably works without making `tbody` and `table` into blocks, it's just tidier that way and prevents unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solution works under the following circumstance:
- your images have a specified height and width:

```css
tr {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  }
td.view-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Haven't tried tough, but should work. idea:
- make the third column independent of normal rendering
- position it below the image
- give it a position and center it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that 1st and 2nd rows texts overlap each other.